# Export Microsoft CRM contacts by marketing list

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to export marketing List members out of the CRM, but simply clicking "Export Marketing List Members" does not give an advanced find options.

I am using advanced find to separate exports because CRM export has a limit of 10 000. Also, how would I add columns (currently only exports first name and phone number).

Comment: Not that I only want the contacts from a particular marketing list.

Comment: I think you might be better off doing an adv find for contacts with related marketing list criteria. Edit: just reread your comment about 10k limit. I think cols you get depend on the mktg list view and its cols and you get what rows are in the view. either setup a view of what you want and export it or manipulate it post export in excel

Comment: Some good info [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6145d004-e93b-40a4-a92c-8bf672a59dbc/crm-2011-how-do-i-change-max-records-for-export-to-excel?forum=crm) too

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Please refrain from doing burning tags untill you have full edit privleges.  see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Advanced Find I assume you already have filters you want to use that can get you the contacts you need, associated to the marketing list.

To change the columns you can click on: Advanced Find -> Edit Columns

(the button is right next to the "Save" button)

[image]

After that you can hit Results and export the data. You can also save the find as a view in case you need to do this more than once and want to save your filter/column settings.